# Change in temporary ASP.NET files folder cause app restart

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP .NET Web API project hosted on IIS. For some reason the app is restarting 2 times, I found the reason using [reflection in Global.asax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/433194):

1. Change in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5e3789de\e7cc3cd0\hash\hash.web
   HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
   HostingEnvironment caused shutdown
2. CONFIG change
   HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown CONFIG change
   HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

I still don't know what is causing these changes (maybe it's an antivirus program), but why does change in 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' cause app restart? My app precompiles during web deploy. Why does these temp files created in precompiled app?

Windows Server 2012R2, IIS 6.2 (Build 9200). OWIN is used.

Comment: Could you please inform us which Windows OS and IIS version you are using? Please inform us, how you find that the app restarts 2 times and there is some change in the config files? Have checked the event viewer logs? Also explain to us, whether you are having any issues with the restart of this app? It could help us understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my question. Because we're running Quartz jobs on app startup (and stopping them on app shutdown after all tasks will be finished) it cause running the jobs in parallel because it will take some time to finish them. Such behavior is not impermissible for our app, jobs shouldn't start in parallel and we need to wait the running jobs executed

Comment: I would suggest you check the Application, Security, and System event viewer logs around the time issue occur. It could give you some information about what is going on in the background.